# How to pop-up TIPS and pop-over any other windows open

Tags: winapi, tooltip, system-tray

Is there any way to pop-up TIPS and pop-over any other windows open? I don't find a flag to set it in NOTIFYICONDATA struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTIFYICONDATA is used with [Shell_NotifyIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx) to place and control icons in the taskbar's notification area.  If you are trying show tooltips or balloon messages from a notification icon, they will normally be at the top of the window order when they appear.  No special action should be required on your part.

In general, to make a window you directly control appear above all other windows, you apply the WS_EX_TOPMOST style, either when creating the window with [CreateWindowEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx) or later using [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx).